# How to create a new string by removing anything that doesn't match a regex from the old one (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string

I have a regex for matching IMDB IDs from input, like so

```
const reg = /(tt[0-9]{7,8})/
```

an input can be any link from IMDB, e.g.

`https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=2K0PR4FAVS54AC50131G&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_4`

What I'm trying to do is make a new string from this input, leaving only the ID.

So the expected output is `tt0468569`

I've only been able to find examples of how to remove everything that *does* match the regex, which is the opposite of what I need.

I want something like

```
const reg = /(tt[0-9]{7,8})/

var input = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=2K0PR4FAVS54AC50131G&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_4"

var result = input.replace(!reg, '')

console.log(result)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do:

The `\d` is for a digit.  You can choose `\d{7,8}` or `\d+` which means 1 or more, or you can use `\d{7,}` to mean 7 or more.

This is the [docs for `match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const s = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=2K0PR4FAVS54AC50131G&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_4"

console.log(s.match(/tt\d{7,8}/)[0]);
```

And we can also guard against the case of not found:

```js
const s = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=2K0PR4FAVS54AC50131G&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_4"

// to guard against "not found":

const matches = s.match(/tt\d{7,8}/);
const id = matches && matches[0];
console.log(id);

// Example when "not found"

const matches2 = s.match(/tt\d{20}/);
const id2 = matches2 && matches2[0];

console.log(id2);
```

The part for `matches && matches[0]`, it means if `matches` is truthy (an array is truthy), then evaluate the second part and take its value. But when there is no match, then `matches` is `null` and is falsy, and then the `&&` will not go on and just take the `null` as the value.

You are trying to match something, so you probably won't use `replace()`, but if you do, it is:

```js
const s = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=2K0PR4FAVS54AC50131G&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_4"

console.log(s.replace(/.*?(tt\d{7,8}).*/, '$1'));
```

The `.*?` means any number of characters and non-greedy, so as to match the first occurrence of `tt_______`. If it is `.*`, that is greedy and the   parenthesized pattern can match the second or last occurrence of `tt_______` if it exists.  So basically matching that pattern and replace with the first parenthesized match.

Comment: yeah, this work perfectly! thank you! I'll accept it as soon as the timer allows